# Php get random jsonobjects from json array

Tags: php, json

I would like to randomize the order of my json objects. Here is the output:

[image: output]

And here is my code so far:

```
// check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
            // temp user array
            $feedMain["user_id"]         = $row["user_id"];

            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["feedMain"], $feedMain);
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

    } 


    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            // temp user array
            $feedMain["user_id"]         = $row["user_id"];

            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["feedMain"], $feedMain);
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

    } 

    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
            // temp user array
            $feedMain["user_id"]         = $row["user_id"];
            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["feedMain"], $feedMain);
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response        
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

I tried something like :

```
echo json_encode(shuffle($response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

and other code snippets but nothing won't work for me..
I just want to randomize the order of the json objects. Thanks.

---

result1,2 and 3 are mysql statements :)

Comment: `shuffle()` returns a boolean, not the shuffled array, so run that call before the json_encode. Also, don't you mean to shuffle `$response['feedMain']` rather than `$response`?

Comment: Also use `sufffle($response['feedMain'])` as I assume you only want to randomize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shuffle` will not walk the array deeply. What you should shuffle is `$response["feedMain"]`:

```
shuffle($response["feedMain"]);
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: yeah, thanks! I always shuffled the full "$response".. It can be so easy! Thank you so much..